# Using multiple libraries in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to load multiple libraries in CI but I'm getting an error.  Here is my controller

```
function index()
{                   
    $this->load->library('materials_library/File_Manager');
    $this->load->library('materials_library/Layout');

    $data = array();

    // Send content to template
    $this->layout->view('materials_library/file_manager', $data, 'ml_cms');
}
```

The error says view is an undefined property.  If I comment out the first `load->library`, I don't get an error.  How do I load multiple libraries in CI?

EDIT:

```
class File_manager
{
    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I read it incorrectly I thought you were using the default load view, do both of the libraries have a layout object?

Comment: No.  Layout has a layout object and File_manager has a file_manager object.

Comment: what version of CI are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load multiple just put them into one array:

```
$this->load->library( array('materials_library/File_Manager', 'another/library') );
```

Comment: I tried that.  I think there is a problem with my File_Manager class.  When I have the m lowercased, it will load.  When I make it upper case, I get an error that I can't redeclare the class.  The file is called File_Manager.php.  Do I have the naming wrong?

Comment: ...yes... you seem to if its not loading, always stick to lowercase unless you really need to, if you are on a linux os this will be case sensitive.

Comment: Oh, I thought classes were supposed to be capitalized.  So to be clear my file name should be file_manager.php and the class should be called file_manager?

Comment: It was a naming issue.  Solved.  Thanks.

Comment: @sehummel What fixed it for you? I have the same issue now as well.

Answer (score 0):

in codeigniter multiple libraries can be loaded at the same time by passing an array of libraries to the load method, see below example:

```
$this->load->library(['email', 'table']);
```

reference: [Codeigniter docs for library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html)